# How to get an attribute from a relation in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-admin

This is part of my code:

```
$form = new Form(new Shop());
$form->tab('terminal', function (Form $form) use ($id) {
        $form->hasMany('shopterminal', '', function (Form\NestedForm $form) {
            $form->text('terminal_num', 'terminal number')->required();
            $form->select('poz_type', 'POS type')->options(['static' => 'one', 'dynamic' => 'two'])->required();
            $form->select('psp_id', 'POZ name')->options(Psp::pluck('name', 'id'))->required();
            $form->text('sheba', 'sheba number');
            $form->text('account_num', 'account number')->required();
            $form->select('bank_id', 'bank name')->options(Bank::pluck('name', 'id'))->required();

    dd($form);

});
```

Here is the result of `dd($form)`:

[image]

I need to get the value of `terminal_image` item (which is `15841949062134.png`). Any idea how can I get it?

Noted that, neither of below syntax works:

- `$form->get('terminal_image')`
- `$form->select('terminal_image')`
- `$form->terminal_image`
- `$form()->terminal_image`
- `$form->relation->terminal_image`

Comment: Did you try to use relation name to get your data, something like this: `$form->shopterminal->terminal_image` ?

Comment: Just twll me one thing where are you trying to catch the termianal image before returning the form or after returning?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example:

```
$form->form->model->shopterminal[0]->terminal_image
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Additionally, I wanted to mention, I think your relationship structure is really weird.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but `$form->form` throws `undefined property`.

Comment: That's weird, the dump you posted shows that `form` property is a `Form` class. Are you maybe iterating over `$forms` then calling `$form->form` for each of those forms? Either way, it would be easier if you updated your question with code for `NestedForm` class, `Form` class, `Shop` class and `TerminalAccount` class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$form->form->model->relations['shopterminal']->items[0]->attributes['terminal_image']
```